# scroll() event not firing when attached to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8" id="homeview-story"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4" id="homeview-stream">
        <div id="log"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#homeview-story {
    overflow: scroll;  
    width: 72%; 
    height: 800px;
}
#homeview-stream { 
    overflow: scroll;  
    width: 28%; 
    height: 800px;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#homeview-story').scroll(function() {
        $("#log").append("<div>Handler for .scroll() called.</div>");
    });
});
```

Objective is to implement infinite scrolling for both `homeview-story` and `homeview-stream` separately to load respective data. The scroll function works on the window obj (`$(window).scroll`) but is not working with specific div.

Comment: it's working [test](http://jsfiddle.net/bL2m51dr/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that, `#homeview-story` isn't overflowing, So it isn't scrolling. First of all it should have some content larger than that for it to scroll, which is missing in your code.

Here's a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1cy0qec9/), where `#logo` has a height greater than it's parent `#homeview-stream` and we're  listening to it's scroll.

Comment: My problem is not exactly solved yet. $('#homeview-story').height = 800 $('#homeview-story')[0].scrollHeight = 1375 So there is content in the div which is greater than the div height. And it still does not work for me.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the code which reproduces this issue, i.e with some sample content, where scroll doesn't work..?

Answer (score 8):

`"scroll"` only works when the element is actually scrollable / scrolling. If you want scroll data regardless of element size, you can use `"wheel"` if your browser supports it.

```
document.addEventListener("wheel", function(event) {
    console.log(event);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I can't see what's not working for you. Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uzdypbjy/)

Have to paste some code so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#homeview-story').scroll(function() {
    $("#log").append("<div>Handler for .scroll() called.</div>");
});
});
```

Comment: Yea, the fiddle seems to work. Well, I am appending lot of tiles (as div tags) inside the scrollable div and this does not work. Could be the issue that content inside homeview-story is not set as it is required to execute scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually scrolling inside the #homeview-story div? So not the page itself, because the jquery scroll() event obvious needs that (http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)

Are you loading your custom CSS after the bootstrap CSS? Otherwise your div might still not be set to overflow:scroll. Hmm, on second thought it probably would since you are referencing an ID. Just to make sure then.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by actually scrolling inside the div. And yes, my css is loaded after the bootstrap css.

Comment: Not sure how to put it better: is the scrollbar at the right hand side of the page or do you have a scrollbar each for both your columns? You need to scroll the div/column itself for the scroll() event to be triggered. So you need to have content larger than 800 pixels inside the columns in your case.

Comment: My problem is not exactly solved yet.
$('#homeview-story').height = 800
$('#homeview-story')[0].scrollHeight = 1375

So there is content in the div which is greater than the div height. And it still does not work for me.

Comment: ok, better update your question with the extent it is not working. I think you should take a look at the fiddles that do work as well. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Put a inner div in #homeview-story

```
<div class="row">
<div id="homeview-story">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div id="homeview-stream"></div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#homeview-story').bind('scroll',function() {
       var html = "<div id='log'>Hello</div>";
       $('#homeview-stream').append(html);
   });
});
```

Hope this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/erwinli/fjc7sv3j/) can help you in what you want to achieve.

Comment: Adding an inner div is not accomplishing anything in itself. Only in your example you set the height so it would overflow the parent div. Adding any substantial amount of content will have the same result and that is how infinite scroll is supposed to work.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same problem as you do, and I solved it by putting that specific selector that I want to be triggered by the `scroll() function` inside the `$(window).scroll() function` like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#homeview-story').scroll(function() {
        $("#log").append("<div>Handler for .scroll() called.</div>");
    });
});
```

I'm not sure if this solution is correct way of fixing this, but works fine for me.

Comment: Doing that, everytime the user scroll the page, the event is going to be bound to the div again...