# How to smooth scroll to div on scroll using vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to scroll to a div on scroll - only on the landing Id not looking for full page scroll across all sections.

The JS in my snippet has worked on click event but can't get it working on scroll

```js
document.getElementById('landing').addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("main").scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
});
```

```css
#landing, #main {
  height:100vh;
}

#main {
  background: #EAEAEA;
}
```

```html
<section id="landing"></section>

<section id="main"></section>
```

Comment: have you read the following article about vanilla smooth implementation:
https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/smooth-scrolling-vanilla-javascript--cms-35165

Comment: My issue is with the scroll event listener not click - this is a good reference though

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that #landing is not overflowing so it isn't scrolling.

I've tried to add more content to the div and it's working

Look at this: [scroll() event not firing when attached to a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26231747/scroll-event-not-firing-when-attached-to-a-div)